# Can a JVM retrieve a list of agents that have been loaded into it via the attach api?

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

Is it possible to get a list of agents loaded into the current JVM by the Java 1.6 attach api? If so how?

Agents loaded at launch can be determined via RuntimeMXBean but I can't see a way to get a handle on ones added after launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a portable way to find out about the agents.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe there is another approach...

Comment: I'm trying to get PIT http://pitest.org to work seamlessly with mocking frameworks such as Powermock and JMockit which use java agents, adding themselves to the current process via attach. If the api doesn't provide a way to detect agents, I'll probably update the PIT agent to intercept loadAgent calls and record the parameters

Comment: I think there is a way how you can find loaded agents by checking the loaded dynamic libraries, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

*(This question is similar to [How to find list of java agents attached with a running JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28670271/2938364). For the sake of completeness, I will add this answer to both questions.)*

---

### Checking agents that have been added using the Attach API:

If you are interested in the agents that have been added to an application at run time using the Attach API, you can use the [`DiagnosticCommandMBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/DiagnosticCommandMBean.html).
This bean offers a diagnostic command called `vmDynlib`, a parameterless method that returns a `String` that list all dynamically loaded libraries.

Here is a snippet that prints all dynamic libraries loaded by the application's VM:

```
ObjectName diagnosticsCommandName = new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand");
String operationName = "vmDynlibs";
String result = (String) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(diagnosticsCommandName, operationName, null, null);
System.out.println(result);
```

This results in an output similar to this one:

```
Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7b8600000 - 0x00007ff7b8637000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffdfeb00000 - 0x00007ffdfecf0000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffdfe300000 - 0x00007ffdfe3b2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffdfbb30000 - 0x00007ffdfbdd3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffdfe950000 - 0x00007ffdfe9f3000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
...
```

You can then check this text if it contains a certain `.so` or `.dll` file.

---

The same inspection can be performed non-programatically.

For this, you can use the [`jconsole`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) tool.

Connect to a VM, switch to the tab `MBeans`, select `com.sun.management`, select `DiagnosticCommand`, select `Operations`, select `vmDynlibs`, and invoke it.

[image: vmDynlibs output]

In the image, you can see one of my test agents attached to the application.
The agent was attached using the [`Attach API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html), thus this agent would not be visible by checking the application's command line arguments (i.e., no `-agentpath=...` would be seen on the arguments) but is only visible as dynamically loaded library.

### Checking agents that have been added via command-line:

To have the complete reference, I will also post how to detect agents that have been added via the command line.
You can check them by using the [`RuntimeMXBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html).

This bean offers the method `getInputArguments`, which returns a list of all VM arguments.
You can iterate over the list and check it for the arguments `agentpath`, `agentlib` and `javaagent`, similar to the following code snippet:

```
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    List<String> jvmArgs = runtimeMXBean.getInputArguments();
    System.out.println("JVM arguments:");
    for (String arg : jvmArgs) {
        if (arg.startsWith("-agentpath") || arg.startsWith("-agentlib") || arg.startsWith("-javaagent")) {
            System.out.print("***** ");
        }

        System.out.print(arg);

        if (arg.startsWith("-agentpath") || arg.startsWith("-agentlib") || arg.startsWith("-javaagent")) {
            System.out.println(" *****");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```